# ¿Cómo elimino los signos de puntuación de mi texto?

Tags: python-3.x, regex

Estoy intentando convertir la variable `texto_minuscula` en una lista pero sin hacer `.split()` y que me elimine todos los signos de puntuación del texto.

Este es mi código:

```
def eliminar_puntuacion(texto_minuscula):
    """La función eliminar_puntuación recibe la variable texto_minuscula elimina los signos de puntuación
    de la lista de palabras y retorna el texto sin signos de puntuación"""
    lista = []
    lista.append(texto_minuscula)
    texto_m_sp = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', texto_minuscula)
    return texto_m_sp

print(eliminar_puntuacion(texto_minuscula))
```

Comment: ¿Los signos de puntuación se reemplazan con un espacio o con cero espacios?

Comment: cero espacios @CandidMoe

Comment: Ok @EnriqueBouthelier entonces debe funcionar sin problema define "import re"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu código debe funcionar sin problema, recuerda agregar  `import re` :

```
import re

def eliminar_puntuacion(texto_minuscula):
    """La función eliminar_puntuación recibe la variable texto_minuscula elimina los signos de puntuación
    de la lista de palabras y retorna el texto sin signos de puntuación"""
    lista = []
    lista.append(texto_minuscula)
    texto_m_sp = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', texto_minuscula)
    return texto_m_sp

#Texto Ejemplo:
texto_minuscula = "hola -.soy, enrique,"

print("",eliminar_puntuacion(texto_minuscula))
```

Como salida tendrías:

```
hola soy enrique
```

Comment: El OP pide separar las palabras en una lista sin usar split().

Answer (score 0):

La función `findall` retorna una lista con todos las subcadenas que cumplen con una cierta expresión regular.

`findall` tiene dos formatos:

- re.findall(patron, texto)
- patron_compilado.findall(texto)

Al trabajar con expresiones regulares es más eficiente compilar el patrón primero una vez y usarlo después múltiples veces, que es lo que haremos aqui.

Ejemplo:

```
import re

patron = re.compile(r'(\S+)')
lista = patron.findall('La mona jacinta se ha puesto una cinta')
print(lista)
```

produce

```
['La', 'mona', 'jacinta', 'se', 'ha', 'puesto', 'una', 'cinta']
```

Veamos el patrón:

- `\S+` calza con una secuencia de caracteres que no sean espacios.
- `(\S+)` calza y además captura la secuencia. Las secuencias capturadas se ponen en la lista.

Con eso, el programa queda asi:

```
import re

patron = re.compile(r'(\S+)')
def eliminar_puntuacion(texto_minuscula):
    """La función eliminar_puntuación recibe la variable texto_minuscula elimina los signos de puntuación
    de la lista de palabras y retorna el texto sin signos de puntuación"""
    texto_m_sp = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', texto_minuscula)
    return patron.findall(texto_m_sp)

texto_minuscula = "la mona jacinta, se-ha puesto una cinta"
print(eliminar_puntuacion(texto_minuscula))
```

produce:

```
['la', 'mona', 'jacinta', 'seha', 'puesto', 'una', 'cinta']
```